# Qt android application not capturing streaming video from local host?

Tags: android, qt, qml, libvlc

I'm creating an android application to capture a streaming data over LAN using a Qt creator using VLC Library. And i'm streaming a video from VLC media player from localhost using RTP protocol.

Working:
Actually the application is able to receive streaming video via LAN, when i build and run my application in ubuntu platform.
Build Tool: Desktop Qt5.10.0 GCC 64-bit.

Not Working: 
But if i build the same application for android (Android for x86/Armv7 ) platform and launching in android emulator.
This time i'm unable to capture a streaming video from local host.

I'm getting following error in Android studio emulator console.
**VideoCapabilities:** Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es

Build Tool: Android x86 GCC 4.9
Emulator Version: Nexus 5X API 26

I tested by changing and not changing  Emulator IP, in both case it is not working.

Code:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
import QmlVlc 0.1
import QtMultimedia 5.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: Screen.width
    height: Screen.height/1.1
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    VlcPlayer {
        id: vlcPlayer;
        mrl: "rtp://@:5000";
    }

    VideoOutput {
        source: vlcPlayer;
        anchors.centerIn: parent;
        //anchors.fill: parent;
        anchors.top: parent.top;
        anchors.left: parent.left;
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom;
        anchors.right: parent.right;
        width: Screen.width-10 ;
        height: Screen.height-10 ;
        anchors.margins: 10
        opacity: 0.9;
    }
    MouseArea
    {
        onClicked: vlcPlayer.pause();
        onDoubleClicked: vlcPlayer.play(vlcPlayer.mrl);
    }

}
```

Please help me out to solve this problem ?

Comment: have you checked if there is any error message through adb?

Comment: Yes, in Android studio, Emulator LogCat i got these errors,   VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es

Comment: edit your question and add it there

Comment: Do you understand the problem now? Clearly the error is caused by VLC, it seems to me that VLC for android does not have the proper codecs or certain types of attributes are not supported in android, I am not an expert in VLC so it is only a speculation, but what I am sure is that you should focus on the problem in VLC and not in QML, maybe so some VLC expert will answer you.

Comment: ok, thank you, Can we use any other media player instead of VLC ?